# How to make imported functions have same param order as the SP?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I Use EF+Ria service for SL app. I generated EF Model from DB. Evenytime when DB have some changes, I update model from DB. But I got nightmare for imported function param order. Because evenytime when update model from DB, the parameter order changed!

WIth EF 4, any Stored Procedure can be imported as function in edmx. When I imported sp, the function has different parameter order  as orginal SP has.

How to enforce imported function have same parameter order as orginal SP has?